# How to check if the Channel i registered

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a problem with my Http Channel. I have a client and a server and in one of the Clients forms, in FormLoad i have this:

```
private void RegisterForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan);

    }
```

And all works fine, but when I close the form, and then if I try to open it Again i get an error:

**RemotingException was unhandled**

**The Channel 'http' is already registered**

Is there any possible way that on the form load to check if the Channel is registered, if it is than just do nothing if it is not than Register the channel???

Comment: I saw tha @rs. but I can't find my answer there

Comment: Did you go through msdn? it is clearly mentioned with example how to get registered channels, the results returned can be used to check if your channel already exists in those results.

Comment: I can't find anything that helps me in that link in that post that you also mentioned... i don't what to do :(...

Comment: Not sure if there is any other way, Why don't you want to use delivered property from same class when you are using method to register channel from same ChannelServices class?

Comment: You can loop through `ChannelServices.RegisteredChannels` can't you?